# Increasing range until get results

Tags: javascript

I have a functionality that submits some parameters via AJAX and displays returned results.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "/ajax.php", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

    request.onload = function() {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {

            document.getElementById("lst").innerHTML = this.response;
            
    };

    request.send("op=list&lt="+lat+"&ln="+lon+"&mi=1");

}, 1500);
```

It works but sometimes no results are found and I need to increase the last parameter "mi" to a higher value and repeat the submission. I decided to create an array and loop through it until I get results.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var dist= new Array(1,5,10,20,50);

    dist.every(v => {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", "/ajax.php", true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

        request.onload = function () {
            if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {    
                document . getElementById("lst") . innerHTML = this . response;
                return false;
            };

            request . send("op=list&lt=" + lat + "&ln=" + lon + "&mi="+v);
            return true;
        }
    });

}, 1500);
```

That's theory, not sure how to put it all together.

Comment: Any reason you're using XHR instead of `fetch`? If not, this should be a lot more ergonomic to implement with `fetch`

Comment: No reason. I normally use jQuery but in this project decided to switch to vanila JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` — those will wait an arbitrary amount of time, which will either be too short (leading to bugs) or too long (leading to poor performance). Instead, wait for each request to finish before starting the next one.

This can be achieved fairly easily with the `fetch` API and `async/await`:

```js
const DISTANCES = [1, 5, 10, 20, 50]

;(async () => {
    const url = new URL('/ajax.php', window.location.origin)

    const headers = new Headers([
        [
            "Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        ],
    ])

    const params = { op: 'list', lt: lat, ln: lon }

    for (const distance of DISTANCES) {
        const res = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers,
            body: new URLSearchParams(Object.entries({
                ...params,
                mi: distance,
            })),
        })

        if (res.ok) {
            document.getElementById("lst").innerHTML = await res.text()

            break
        }
    }
})()
```

Comment: Oh, I use SetTimeout to start with this functionality after my map loads and does some other stuff.

Comment: Ideally, you'd use an event listener or similar for that. Any time you use `setTimeout` to wait for something, you create a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
var dist= new Array(1,5,10,20,50);
(function loop(i, length) {
    if (i>= length) {
        return;
    }
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", "/ajax.php", true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

    request.onload = function() {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
            document . getElementById("lst") . innerHTML = this . response;
            loop(i + 1, length);
    };
        
    }
    request.send("op=list&lt=" + lat + "&ln=" + lon + "&mi="+dist[i]);
})(0, index.length);
```